# Verificando grupos com a API da Steam [PHP]

Tags: php

Preciso descobrir qual dos GroupID's se refere a este grupo em específico http://steamcommunity.com/groups/NewSteamCommunityBeta

A lista de ID's dos grupos de um usuário eu consigo através desse request:
http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetUserGroupList/v1/?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&steamid=76561198077945243

Como eu poderia fazer essa verificação em PHP ?

Answer (score 2):

Só adicionar "memberslistxml/?xml=1" no final da URL.

Isso faz a página retornar um XML que você pode "puxar" com o cURL e XMLSimpleObject.

O link completo seria:

```
http://steamcommunity.com/groups/NewSteamCommunityBeta/memberslistxml/?xml=1
```

@EDIT

Existem, na página do grupo, algumas tags que acabam por mostrar o id desse grupo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você pode tentar acessá-la do file_get_contents('urldogrupo'); e depois com um preg_match(); capturar essas informações.

Comment: O problema é que se eu fizer isso para cada gID ele retorna "Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded" e não completa a verificação.

Comment: @RobertLang você pode tentar otimizar o seu código para rodar mais rápido ou aumentar o maximum execution time do PHP ou Fazer um banco de dados com as GroupIDs no seu servidor.

Comment: @RobertLang Acabei de procurar e, no código fonte da página, existem alguns locais que acabam mostrando o ID do grupo. Vou atualizar a resposta com essas informações.

Comment: Eu aproveitei essa ideia que você me falou de pegar as informações diretamente da página e eu vi que seria mais fácil eu verificar se o usuário é membro ou não através do botão de "Join Group" com um preg_match, o problema é que ele sempre retorna o "Join Group" mesmo quando eu já sou membro do grupo.